# Can't read 'package:rikulo_commons/html.dart' (Could not find asset rikulo_commons|lib/html.dart.)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, dart, dart-pub, rikulo, bootjack

After following the directions at:

https://github.com/rikulo/bootjack

When I try to "generate js" from the Dart Editor I get the error message:

```
[Info from Dart2JS]:
Compiling StratoIde|web/ide.dart...
[Error from Dart2JS on StratoIde|web/ide.dart]:
packages\bootjack\bootjack.dart:8:8:
Can't read 'package:rikulo_commons/html.dart' (Could not find asset      rikulo_commons|lib/html.dart.).
import 'package:rikulo_commons/html.dart';
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[Info from Dart2JS]:
Took 0:00:01.048060 to compile StratoIde|web/ide.dart. 
[Info from Dart2JS]:
Compiling StratoIde|web/index.dart...
[Error from Dart2JS on StratoIde|web/index.dart]:
packages\bootjack\bootjack.dart:8:8:
Can't read 'package:rikulo_commons/html.dart' (Could not find asset   rikulo_commons|lib/html.dart.).
import 'package:rikulo_commons/html.dart';
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[Info from Dart2JS]:
Took 0:00:00.414024 to compile StratoIde|web/index.dart.
Build failed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually `pub cache repair` helps in such cases.